# String concatenation with ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a `SelectList` of various contacts. I want the text shown to be a combination of `FirstName`, `MiddleInit`(if possible), and `LastName`.

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = contacts
.Select(r => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = r.ContactID.ToString(),
    Text = r.FirstName + " " 
    + string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MiddleInit) ? r.MiddleInit + ". " : ""
    + r.LastName
});
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error   4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'   C:\Users\cu551d\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WVM\WVM\Controllers\SOWController.cs  181 15  WVM
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my syntax. Am I able to do something like this in c#?

Also, should I include a `Trim()` statement on `MiddleInit`? I thought this error was very strange as `IsNullOrEmpty` does in fact return a bool. I also tried `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MiddleInit) == true ) ..`

Comment: is r.MiddleInt a string or a bool?

Comment: Operator precedence. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: r.MiddleInit is a string

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try grouping in parenthesis. It also looks like you're doing the conditional operator backwards:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = contacts
.Select(r => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = r.ContactID.ToString(),
    Text = r.FirstName + " " +
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MiddleInit) ? "" : (r.MiddleInit + ". ")) +
        r.LastName
});
```

#### Another Technique

Since you are converting it to empty string anyway, you might consider this too:

```
Text = r.FirstName + " " + (r.MiddleInit ?? "") + r.LastName
```

The `??` is called the `Null Coalescing Operator`. It will return whatever is on the left if that value is not null, otherwise whatever is on the right.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

**EDIT**: while cleaner, this won't quite work for your case since you need the period after the initial. But be aware it does exist!

Comment: Wrapping the expression is definitely the solution.

Comment: Wrapping it works. Thanks for pointing out the backward-ness... How would your second technique using `??` work in the case of whitespace or an empty string? If I trim `r.MiddleInit`, that still leaves the case of an empty string right? What would be the best practice way to handle this?

Comment: It wouldnt, you had IsNullOrEmpty, the end result of your conditional operator being the string or an empty. But in your case, you are adding the period after the initial, so the null-coalescing operator won't quite get you there.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is due to operator precedence causing the compiler to parse the expression in a way that you're not expecting.  Just wrapping the ternary expression in parens will politely explain to the compiler what it is you mean to say.

As a side note, looking at the logic of the expression, I think the order of the result terms is incorrect.  I've switched them in the code below.

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = contacts
.Select(r => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = r.ContactID.ToString(),
    Text = r.FirstName + " " 
    + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MiddleInit) ? "" : r.MiddleInit + ". ")
    + r.LastName
});
```

**More explanation**

Without `(`, `+` has a higher precedence than `?:`, so the expression in your question is being parsed as if it said:

```
Test = (r.FirstName + " " + string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MiddleInit)) ? (r.MiddleInit + ". ") : ("" + r.LastName)
```

So the source of your error is that the conditiional part of the `?:` operator is actually a string - which will contain something like "Andrew true".  Also note that `r.LastName` gets combine with the third term of the `?:` operator.

**The Trim() question**

If there's a chance that `r.MiddleInit` could contain whitespace, then using `Trim()` would help, but it would be better to change the test to `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.MiddleInit)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your arguments in your ternary

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = contacts
.Select(r => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = r.ContactID.ToString(),
    Text = r.FirstName + " " 
    + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MiddleInit) ? (r.MiddleInit + ". ") : ("" + r.LastName))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the arguments, just the ternary...

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = contacts
.Select(r => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = r.ContactID.ToString(),
    Text = r.FirstName + " " 
    + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MiddleInit) ? r.MiddleInit + ". " : "")
    + r.LastName
});
```

I found by trying it out that I actually needed...

```
(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MiddleInit) ? r.MiddleInit + ". " : "")
```

for it to work right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$"{data.CreateDate.ToString("hh:mm tt")}, {(data.CreateDate.Day == DateTime.Now.Day ? "Today": data.CreateDate.Day+"ago")}"
```